# Audit.NET The foreign key property 'AuditQuantitativeResearch.AuditId' was detected as changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, audit.net

In my project, I have a lot of tables and am using Audit.NET to track all the changes in the records. It is working well. I have a long process where I save each row from an Excel file into the database. In production environment, I found this error

> The foreign key property 'AuditQuantitativeResearch.AuditId' was detected as changed. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see property values.

> {"AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Production","OriginalFormat":"The foreign key property '{entityType}.{property}' was detected as changed. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see property values.","CategoryName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking","EventName":"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.ForeignKeyChangeDetected","EventId":"10803","entityType":"AuditQuantitativeResearch","property":"AuditId"}

[image]

That causes a very long process and the procedure doesn't save anything in the database.

The definition of the table is like

```
public class QuantitativeResearch : ITable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;

    // more properties
}
```

and the Audit table connected to this one is

```
public class AuditQuantitativeResearch : IAudit
{
    [Key]
    public long AuditId { get; set; }

    public long ID { get; set; }
}
```

The base repository for adding a new record is like that

```
public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
{
    _log.LogDebug($"[{nameof(T)}] Adding a new record");

    try
    {
        _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
        await _db.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _log.LogError(ex, "Adding a new record");
    }

    return entity;
}
```

The audit and all the add/update/delete is working for all the other entities. On the dev environment (some server than the production under IIS but different pool) and locally the process is working also with this table.

### Update

This is the configuration of Audit.NET

```
public static IServiceCollection ConfigureAudit(
       this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, 
       string connString)
{
    #region Use this when you have another table for audit

    Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()
        .UseEntityFramework(ef => ef.AuditTypeExplicitMapper(m => m
            .Map<QuantitativeResearch, AuditQuantitativeResearch>()
            .AuditEntityAction<IAudit>((evt, entry, auditEntity) =>
            {
                auditEntity.AuditDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                auditEntity.UserName = evt.Environment.UserName;
                auditEntity.AuditAction = entry.Action;
            }))); ;

    #endregion Use this when you have another table for audit

    return serviceCollection;
}
```

Those are the packages I'm using

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Audit.EntityFramework.Core" Version="18.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Audit.NET" Version="18.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Audit.NET.SqlServer" Version="18.1.5" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="5.0.9" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.9">
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
  </PackageReference>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.9" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="5.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

As side note, I have other 101 tables with the same configuration but only this one has this issue. The configuration is the same, the proprieties between the main table and the Audit table are the same.

Comment: As the error message said, "The foreign key property 'AuditQuantitativeResearch.AuditId' was detected as changed", you can use the 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see property values, or check the relate table foreign key configuration, in your code try to use Fluent Configuration API to configure the foreign key. Besides, here is an article about [Changing relationships using navigations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes#changing-relationships-using-navigations), you can refer it.

Comment: Also, please share your configuration for `Audit.Core` and `Audit.EntityFramework`

Comment: Do you have a foreign key that points to `AuditQuantitativeResearch.AuditId`?

Comment: No, I don't have any foreign key to `AuditId`. The audit tables are unlinked to everything